# FrameLayout not respecting draw order

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout, z-order, view-hierarchy

I've this layout hierarchy:

```
<FrameLayout>

    <ScrollView>...</ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout>...</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout>...</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Using the **Android Device Monitor** I've dumped the view hierarchy and I've achieved this:

[image: view dump 1]

As expected. But if I include two more layouts:

```
<FrameLayout>

    <ScrollView>...</ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout>...</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout>...</LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/a_framelayout"/>

    <include layout="@layout/another_framelayout"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Note: `a_framelayout` contains a `LinearLayout` and `another_framelayout` contains a `View`.

I get this:

[image: view dump 2]

Shouldn't this two layouts have a index of 3 and 4 respectively instead of 0 and 2? And why is the `ScrollView` between them?

If I change the layout to:

```
<FrameLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/a_framelayout"/>

    <include layout="@layout/another_framelayout"/>

    <ScrollView>...</ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout>...</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout>...</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I get:

[image: view dump 3]

It makes more sense, but now the `a_framelayout` was swapped with `another_framelayout`, why?

Although this strange layout behaviour happened, all views were correctly rendered in the screen and the layout works as it should.

Any clue?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: did you try to call ViewGroup.getChildAt ?

Comment: I did not actually, but now that you asked I've tried and the views are ordered in the correct order. So, do this means that Android Device Monitor could be displaying it wrong?

Comment: could be... the question is: do you **see** the wrong order of your views on the screen?

Comment: No I don't, all views are rendered in the correct order.